# Calculate and average range

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Calculate and average range of Boeing model in table `aircraft` of a database.

This is the `aircraft` table:

[image]

I know

```
SELECT AVG(range) FROM aircraft;
```

but I only need the range of Boeing model only. I tried

```
WHERE model LIKE "B%"
```

because it will select row which start with B but I am still getting error.

**Update:**
As requested, my full query is:

```
SELECT AVG(range) 
FROM aircraft 
WHERE model LIKE "B%"
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: column "B%" does not exist LINE 3: WHERE model LIKE "B%
```

Comment: Please add your query , your expected result and the full error message.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: => SELECT AVG(range)
-> FROM aircraft
-> WHERE model LIKE "B%";
ERROR:  column "B%" does not exist
LINE 3: WHERE model LIKE "B%"; the expect result should be avg: 73.33333

Comment: Logically that's incorrect anyway Bombardier starts with a B too - (unless Bombardier is a part of Boing).ALSO range is a reserved word and needs to be backticked.

Comment: try use single quote   LIKE 'B%';

Answer (score 2):

String literals in SQL are denoted by single quotes (`'`), not double quotes (`"`):

```sql
SELECT AVG(range)
FROM   aircraft
WHERE  model LIKE 'B%'
-- Here ----------^--^
```

Note, also, that this query would include the model "Bombardier CRJ-200", so you may want to spell out Boeing explicitly:

```sql
SELECT AVG(range)
FROM   aircraft
WHERE  model LIKE 'Boeing%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [Regex](https://www.sqlshack.com/t-sql-regex-commands-in-sql-server/).
Try this piece of code:

```
SELECT AVG(range)
FROM aircraft
WHERE model LIKE ‘[B][o][e][i][n][g]%’
```